# Enumerate symlink using udev rules with udev that doesn't support %e

Tags: linux, ansible, filesystems, udev

I'm using a version of udev (on Centos7) that doesn't support the [%e naming for a device](https://linux.die.net/man/8/udev), but I'd like to use feature it provides.

Specifically, I've got several NVME devices, make of two different types, which are all available on a cluster of hardware, but may not be plugged into exact locations. I'd like to enumerate them so that I can proceed to use Ansible or some other management tool to programatically partition, add a filesystem, and mount the drive. Specifically, I'd ultimately like to do something like `mkfs.ext4 /dev/type1nvme1 -L nvme1` and `mkfs.ext4 /dev/type2nvme1 -L different_nvme1` - but of course in order to do so I need the devices in the same `/dev` location every time.

I've looked at this answer as a guide:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105144/udev-rule-for-assigning-known-symlinks-for-identical-usb-serial-devices

However, the big problem is, it would appear that udev is multithreaded and enumerating several devices at a time - so the script fails. I've got some 18 nvme devices of two types, and I generally only get symlinks for about 6 or 7 of them, and the numbers are wrong. Here's the udev rules, as well as the script I'm using:

```
# all nvme devices
KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]", SUBSYSTEMS=="nvme"\
, ATTR{queue/read_ahead_kb}="4096"\
, ATTR{queue/rotational}="0"\
, ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none"

# Better rename type1 cards
KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]", ATTRS{model}=="Dell Express Flash PM1725a*"\
, PROGRAM="/usr/local/sbin/unique-num /dev disktype1"\
, SYMLINK+="disktype1%c"
#
# Better rename internal nvme (primary seg) cards
KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]", ATTRS{model}=="Dell Express Flash NVMe P4600*"\
, PROGRAM="/usr/local/sbin/unique-num /dev disktype2"\
, SYMLINK+="disktype2 %c"
```

```
# cat /usr/local/sbin/unique-num 
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 location prefix" >&2
    exit 1
fi

location="$1"
prefix="$2"

needindex=1
index=0

while [ $needindex -eq 1 ]
do
        if [ ! -e $location/$prefix$index ]; then
                needindex=0
                echo "$index"
        else
                (( index++ ))
        fi
done
```

And after a `udevadm trigger`:

```
[root@sdw1 ~]# ls -l /dev/disk_type*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type10 -> nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type11 -> nvme1n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type12 -> nvme2n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type13 -> nvme3n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type14 -> nvme4n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type15 -> nvme9n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type20 -> nvme7n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type21 -> nvme13n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type22 -> nvme16n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Apr  2 18:56 /dev/disk_type23 -> nvme14n1
```

So in short - is there any way to get the %e naming behavior for udev for a version that doesn't support it?

Comment: Have you considered updating to the version that does support the feature you want?

Comment: I don't find any version of RHEL/centos which supports udev that has the `%e` modifier. It seems to be an old/deprecated option. It's also not available on Ubuntu, according to [their man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/udev.7.html)

Comment: Turns out the issue was a udev induced race condition. Setting udev max workers to "1" with `udevadm control -m 1` "resolves" the problem with triggering, and we can work to make sure the script handles multithreading from udev.